# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'member')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Can someone help me figure out this error? I really dont know what to do. I  tried my best to get rid of this error, but nothing worked. I will be very grateful if you try to help me.
This code is supposed to give you basic information about user that you pinged.[image]

```
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 * @param {Message} message
 * @param {String[]} args 
 */

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "userinfo",
    description: 'info',

    async run(client, message, args) {
        const user = message.mentions.member.first() || message.member.user.username;
        const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('DARK_RED')
            .setAuthor({ name: user.username, iconURL: user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setDescription("Kdo to je")
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .addFields(
            { name: "Username", value: user.username, inline: true }, 
            { name: "Tag", value: user.discriminator, inline: true }, 
            { name: "Bot", value: user.bot, inline: true }, 
            { name: "Nickname", value: member.nickname || "None", inline: true },
            { name: "Joined:", value: new Date(member.joinedTimestamp()).toDateString(), inline: true },
            { name: "Discord user since:", value: new Date(user.createdTimestamp()).toDateString(), inline: true },
            { name: "Roles count:", value: member.roles.cache - 1, inline: true },

            )

        return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }

})
```

Im also sharing my simple command handler, because its used in this code.

```
const Client = require("./Client.js");

/**
 * @param {Discord.Message} message 
 * @param {string[]} args 
 * @param {Client} client 
 */
function RunFunction(message, args, client) {}


class Command {

    /**
     * @typedef {{name: string, description: string, run: RunFunction}} CommandOptions
     * @param {CommandOptions} options 
     */
    constructor(options) {
        this.name = options.name;
        this.description = options.description;
        this.permission = options.permission;
        this.run = options.run;
    }
}

module.exports = Command;
```

Comment: You should give more details to let others understand what you are doing. For example, what libraries are you using and what you have achieved correctly and what not and what do you expect from your code to do!!

Comment: Can you please provide a StackTrace for the given error. Does it occur on the first line within `run()`? You should make sure a property `member` exists on the object you are trying to access it.

Comment: I'm guessing by speculation that in your code where it says `const user = message.mentions.member.first()` mentions is actually a list, you have to select a single mention from this list and then proceed to access its members. Try doing `message.mentions[0].member.first()` to get the first mention of this message, (be wary that the mssage might not have any mentions)

Comment: Already updated this question. I added my command handler and i print screened the console.

Answer (score 1):

One of the following does not contain object:

`message.mentions.member` or `message.member` or `message.guild.members`

Therefore when you try to access i.e. `message.mentions.member.first()` it fails, because you try to call something like `undefined.first()`

You should log (or debug) the whole `message` parameter and see what is actually inside.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. Am not really good at javascript, this bot is my first experience with javascript, but im trying my best